# Revert back not possible in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have 3 box with id `div1`, and a box with id `drag1`.  The box drag1 can be dragged and dropped to any of box div1.

I want to know if there is a way that the div `drag1` can be seen during the drag in javascript - like in jquery.

Is there any revert back possible because I don't want to completely change the function to jquery

How to achieve this?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
 }
 
 function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
 }
 
 function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  
  
 }
 
/* 
  $("#drag1").draggable({
     revert: "valid",
     drag: function (event, ui) {
       $("#info").html("<font color=red>This square will go back to it`s original position once it`s dropped in target zone. </font>");
     }
   });
   
      
$("#div1").droppable({
 drop: function (event, ui)
  {
 $(this).css("background-color", "lightgreen")
 },
 out: function (event, ui) 
  {
 $(this).css("background-color", "")
 }
   });
 });   
  
  */
```

```css
#div1 {
    width:120px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>


<img id="drag1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" 
draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100" style="border:solid">
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking as, in your snippet, dragging the image shows the image as I drag it.  What do you mean by "like in jquery"?  (I get that you want a vanilla answer)

Comment: @hfreedomn-m during the drag lement is not visible

Comment: @freedomn-m is revet back possible in javascript

Comment: Revert back, as in this example: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#revert

Comment: @freedomn-m yes

Comment: is it possible in js

Comment: In the same example (jquery ui revert), dragging the left item moves it away from the DOM, in your code snippet, it stays in the DOM, but also is shown under the cursor (which browser are you using?).  It's not clear if you want to hide it when you start dragging or if you want it shown under the cursor as you drag (which the browser does for you).

Comment: Well, obviously, "is it possible" is **yes**, because jquery and jquery-ui *is* javascript.  Just they've kindly written it for you already and fixed any the bugs.

Comment: i want the element to be shown under the cursor

Comment: I have done a lot many functionalities inside this function drop(ev),  so when the dragged element ad droped element does not match i need a revet back, is it possible to inclue it in function drop(ev).

Comment: Then can't help you, because that's what (my) browser already does.  Tried in Chrome, IE11 and IEdge and all of them "show the image under the cursor as you drag", using your snippet (the 2x IEs didn't allow a drop)

Comment: can you help with revert back

Comment: @geek you will have to write a function that will animate the revert activity. This is normally done using `.animate()` in jQuery, but you want a vanilla JS solution. Your script will simply need to adjust the CSS Top & left of the item until it reaches it's destination.

Comment: @geek looking at your snippet, you have jQuery 2.1.1 so you could use `.animate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in HTML, you must have unique IDs for each element, so `div1` cannot be the ID for all three.

This example of mine is poorly put together and it gives you something to start with. You didn't include in your post what would be needed to trigger a `revert` event. my example only reverts a Drag if it is dragged to a Drop that has `revert` class name.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  var boxData = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("original-position-top", boxData.top);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("original-position-left", boxData.left);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  if (ev.target.className == "revert") {
    var el = document.getElementById(data);
    el.style.position = "relative";
    var startPosition = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    startPosition = {
      top: startPosition.top,
      left: startPosition.left
    };
    var targetPosition = {
      top: ev.dataTransfer.getData("original-position-top"),
      left: ev.dataTransfer.getData("original-position-left")
    };
    console.log("Trigger Revert", el.id, startPosition, targetPosition);

    function calcSteps(start, finish) {
      var l = Math.abs(start.left - finish.left);
      var t = Math.abs(start.top - finish.top);
      return {
        top: t,
        left: l,
        pick: (l > t ? "left" : "top")
      };
    }
    var steps = calcSteps(startPosition, targetPosition);
    console.log("Steps:", steps);
    var a = setInterval(frame, 2);

    function frame() {
      var i = steps.pick;
      console.log("Animate Frame:", steps[i]);
      if (steps[i] <= 0) {
        clearInterval(a);
      } else {
        if (startPosition.left + 1 > targetPosition.left) {
          // Do nothing
        } else {
          startPosition.left++;
          el.style.left = startPosition.left + "px";
        }
        if (startPosition.top + 1 > targetPosition.top) {
          // Do nothing
        } else {
          startPosition.top++;
          el.style.top = startPosition.top + "px";
        }
        console.log("Animate Frame:", steps[i], startPosition);
        steps[i]--;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#div1,
#div2,
#div3 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="revert"></div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100" style="border:solid">
```

Hope that helps.